# Правильно ли предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Многие социальные сети: VK, FB, OK –– позволяют пользователям отправлять фотографии, загружать видео-файлы и т.п.

Интересует обобщающее слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас интересует только пунктация при обобщающем слове и однородных членах предложения, то да, верно.

Comment: Спасибо, что подтвердили.